# How to improve these haskell compress and decompress functions?

Tags: haskell, compression

Specify the function that compresses a list by converting identical consecutive elements into number-by-element pairs. The group function can be useful.

Specify the function that restores the original from a compressed list. The replicate function can be useful.

```
import Data.List


compress :: (Eq a, Integral b) => [a] -> [(b, a)]
compress l = zip (length $ group l) (head $ group l)
Or:
compress :: (Eq a, Integral b) => [a] -> [(b, a)]
compress [] = []
compress (x:xs) 
    | x == a = (b+1,a) : xs
    | otherwise = (1,a) : compress (b,a) xs



decompress :: (Eq a, Integral b) => [(b, a)] -> [a]
decompress l = concat [replicate (fst x) (snd x) | x <- l]



Examples:
compress "aaaabccaadeeee" == [(4, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'd'), (4, 'e')]
compress "oh hello !!" == [(1, 'o'), (1, 'h'), (1, ''), (1, 'h'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'l'), (1, 'o'), (2, '!')]
compress [] == []
compress [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1] == [(2.1), (3.0), (3.1)]

decompress [(4, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'd'), (4, 'e')] == "aaaabccaadeeee"
decompress [(1, 'o'), (1, 'h'), (1, ''), (1, 'h'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'l'), ( 1, 'o'), (2, '!')] == "oh hello !!"
decompress [] == []
decompress [(2,1), (3,0), (3,1)] == [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are here enumerating over the result of a `group` twice. You can simplify this and work with a mapping function that transforms each item of the result of group to a 2-tuple, for example with [**`(&&&) :: Arrow a => a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c, c')`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-). [**`length :: Foldable f => f a -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length) returns an `Int`, so you can not use any `Integral` type:

```
import Control.Arrow((&&&))

compress :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
compress = map (length &&& head) . group
```

For decompressing, we can make use of [**`concatMap :: Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap)  and use [**`uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) to create a variant of `replicate` that works on a 2-tuple instead. [**`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) works on an `Int`, not any `Integral`, and the `Eq` type constraint is *not* necessary here, since we can replicate any item. `concatMap` can work on any `Foldable`, so we can generalize the type signature to:

```
decompress :: Foldable f => f (Int, a) -> [a]
decompress = concatMap (uncurry replicate)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can not change the type signature, I have to solve them with the aktual type signature.

Comment: @batat: you can use `genericLength` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericLength and `genericReplicate` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericReplicate for more generic versions to calculate the length and replicate.